# Parsing RealLegal's .PTX file format

Tags: macos, file-format

Anyone have experience parsing the RealLegal PTX file format? I'm interested in creating a Mac reader client for this proprietary format.

The PTX file format is in wide use for storing court and deposition transcripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it's proprietary you're probably unlikely to find any public specification of it. However, given also that they don't appear to have a Mac presence, perhaps it might be worth it to enter into a business relationship with RealLegal? Sounds like a great proposal to help them expand the *.ptx market share (good for them) and for you to build a software product that presumably has some demand (good for you).